# MySQL GUI Tools 5.5

Tags: mysql

When I am editing a record, Query stopped working after close open query browser not showing any data.
I create backup, Table etc. But only query browser not working.Image When select Edit Table Data shows:

[image: Query Browser image]

Comment: What tool is this? Is it the latest version?

Comment: Please share more details - how is this related to programming?